# How to prepare dependencies before playing in a Intellij Idea repl?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

Say I want to play with a some clojure library, but inside  the  REPL from Intellij Idea. How do I start that REPL prepared? Or for that matter, how I load that library anyway, even after the start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With IntelliJ, library directories inside the project can be included in the Java classpath that's used when starting the REPL. These can then be used in the REPL through Clojure's "use" or "require".

The easiest way to get the libraries into the project is through Leiningen and IntelliJ's Leiningen plug-in. Leiningen is a build and dependency management tool for Clojure.

Download and install Leiningen. Install IntelliJ's Leiningen plugin. Open IntelliJ's setting screen and under IDE Settings > Leiningen, enter the path to the Leiningen executable.

From the IntelliJ project window, create a Clojure file named project.clj in the root. Edit this file  using the Leiningen syntax to define the libraries that project depends on. Use the Leiningen library name from the library entry at clojars.org (the main clojure library repository), or the project's webpage.

From the Leiningen plug-in menu, add (+ icon) the project.clj. Now in the Leiningen plugin screen, click the project name to open it's tree, choose the "deps" option, and click the "play" icon from the menu. This will make Leiningen download the libraries, and place them in the correct (/lib) folder of the project.

Now rightclick the project name in the project windows,  choose Open Module Settings > Modules > Dependencies > Add > Library > Name (Enter name) > Attach Jar Directories (Choose /lib)

Then start the REPL, load the library with "use" or "require" and you're all set.

Comment: thanks for the walk-through. did not know that libraries inside the project are included in the Java classpath (usefull info). will give it a try

Comment: After trying out Netbeans & Enclojure (needs Maven for dependencies), Eclipse & CounterClockwise (manually adding each Lein added library to project, and manually adding Lein functions to Eclipse) and IntelliJ & La Clojure & Leiningen plugin, I found IntelliJ the easiest to use. Be sure to add rainbow parentheses in la Clojure settings (also a feature in CounterClockwise). Only minor niggle I have is La Clojure REPL autocompletion not respecting the libraries in the current namespace. Not a problem sending lines from file editor to REPL.

Comment: one extra thing to add is, once the libraries are downloaded, the folder might need to be added by hand as a jar folder under dependencies under module settings

Comment: Sorry about that, been working on one big project for some time, and forgot I probably set that directory manually. Too bad the Leiningen plugin doesn't do that automatically.  Still, better than having to enter all libraries manually like I had to do in Eclipse (still thinking there should be a way to include a dir there as well, just couldn't seem to get it working).

Comment: What is "the Leiningen plug-in menu"?

Comment: install cursive plugin and find from views menu the intellij toolbox

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on NielsK's answer, but can not for some reason... anyway
make sure that Maven is enabled in the IDE, since leiningen generates a POM that IDEA uses to import the dependencies.

Comment: To clarify: You can run `lein pom` and then import the generated `pom.xml` in IntelliJ.